# How to fix "Field {$foreign_key} doesn't have a default value" error when updating a belongsTo relationship with associate method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have created a eloquent relationship "one to one" between two models `TokenMatch` model and `Match` model but when I tried to associate TokenMatch to a Match I have an error:

```
"Field 'tokenmatch_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `matches` (`id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 2019-04-22 08:55:51, 2019-04-22 08:55:51))
"
```

My code issue:

```
$match = new Match();
$tokenmatch = TokenMatch::find(1);
$match->token()->associate($tokenmatch)->save();
```

class Match

```
class Match extends Model
{

    public function token()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\TokenMatch' , 'id', 'tokenmatch_id');
    }
}
```

class TokenMatch

```
class TokenMatch extends Model
{
    protected  $table = 'tokensmatch';

    public function match()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Match','tokenmatch_id');
    }
}
```

matches Table

```
 Schema::create('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->boolean('isFinished')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('isWon')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('tokenmatch_id');
            $table->foreign('tokenmatch_id')->references('id')->on('tokensmatch');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

        });
```

tokensmatch Table

```
 Schema::create('tokensmatch', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->boolean('isUsed')->default(false);
            $table->string('token', 15)->unique();
            $table->dateTimeTz('expiryDate')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('isValid')->default(true);
        });
```

So I expected that on field "tokenmatch_id" of table Matches is not null when I save the new model match

```
...
$match->token()->associate($tokenmatch)->save();
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is an issue with the relationship you defined in `Match` model. It should be :

```
public function token()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\TokenMatch' ,'tokenmatch_id', 'id');
}
```

Please refer:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('tokenmatch_id');
```

to

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('tokenmatch_id')->nullable();
```

Comment: Is not correct because doing so the record match would have a null value on the tokenmatch_id field and result is that my relationship does not exist